# Is it possible to add an overlay in google maps api on user side e.g. with rmb click?

Tags: php, javascript, api, overlay

I'm working on a project of mine, which would require users to add markers on a google maps api map, that would be later on passed to a DB, which would store all overlay coordinates and once the map is loaded (in case the user has the required permissions, of course), a for loop will add all markers from the DB into the page and will visualize them  (circles with static radius, but various coordinates). So long story short, I need a way to enable the users to put those markers themselves there and a way to read the LatLng coordinates and pass them to a script, which will flush them in the DB. One way (in case it's possible, of course) is to use the context menu and add an option like "set marker here", that would pass the coords to a function flushing them to the DB. Of course the workaround is RMB-> what is here, copy the coords and enter 'em in a input field, which almost inevitably will doom the project to an epic fail, because nobody will do that, but instead will just enter some random numbers, which would be moronic, because the project basically depends on those coordinates.

So is there a way to somehow automate the adding process of an overlay element in the api, that I could use? I googled around for a few days, tried to find something in the v3 help too, but didn't find anything really helpful so far..

Thanks in advance! All comments and help would be appreciated!

Cheers,
vlex